# Changing the text of Upload/Insert on Posts and Pages Screen

Tags: functions, hooks, filters

In wp-admin/includes/media.php I found this:

```
function media_buttons($editor_id = 'content') {
    $context = apply_filters('media_buttons_context', __('Upload/Insert %s'));

    $img = '<img src="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'images/media-button.png?ver=20111005' ) ) . '" width="15" height="15" />';

    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_upload_iframe_src() ) . '" class="thickbox add_media" id="' . esc_attr( $editor_id ) . '-add_media" title="' . esc_attr__( 'Add Media' ) . '" onclick="return false;">' . sprintf( $context, $img ) . '</a>';
}
add_action( 'media_buttons', 'media_buttons' );
```

I don't know what I'm doing to change the text from Upload/Insert in my functions.php file. I've tried what I have below and it doesn't work.

```
function adcp_change_media_button($context) {
    return str_replace('Upload/Insert %s', 'Upload/Insert images, documents, etc %s');
}
add_filter('media_buttons', 'adcp_change_media_button');
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function adcp_change_media_button( $context ) 
{
    // $context acutally IS 'Upload/Insert %s', so we simply drop in in some other string
    return __( 'Upload/Insert images, documents, etc %s', 'YOUR_TEXTDOMAIN' );
}
// Then use the right filter name
add_filter( 'media_buttons_context', 'adcp_change_media_button' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What do I put for YOUR_TEXTDOMAIN? Just the domain? Out of curiosity, What is the purpose of it?

Comment: It's the textdomain for your theme. You need, because else the system would search for a matching string inside the WP translation files, which would fail silently and cost time. It doesn't matter if your theme doesn't have an translation file (.po/.mo file endings - translated with POEdit - read on codex about it).